# How replicate data using PCA

Tags: pca

I have a set of date covering petrol prices.

My example has two columns where each row represents a sequential date.

```
   unleaded diesel
1   1.39     1.35
2   1.3901   1.3502
3   1.3902   1.3501
.....
```

I generate eigen values:

my.eigen $values [1] 7.053791e-07 9.097811e-08

```
$vectors
             PC1        PC2
unleaded 0.6489256 -0.7608519
diesel   0.7608519  0.6489256
```

my.eigen $values [1] 7.053791e-07 9.097811e-08

How can I produce a timeseries using the first, second or first two Components. That would give me something that replicates(but of course is different to) the original data?

I would like to plot unleaded, diesel timeseries against the "replicated" data for different inclusion of components.

Comment: At first glance it's difficult to see whether using PCA makes any sense here. Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve? Generate similar data?

Comment: @SRKK I understand it is possible to apply the eigenvectors to the original data (not sure of exactly how) and generate a new timeseries that looks very much like unleaded BUT is based on just a subset of the principa components.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Can my answer [here](http://quant.stackexchange.com/a/4628/467) help you already?

Comment: @SRKX - Yes that's exactly where I am trying to go. I have added a comment on that question - as I do not understand your final suggestion.

Comment: One of the main uses for PCA is to reduce the dimension of correlated data in such a way as to discover the best combination of independent vectors that can be combined linearly to explain the 'variance' of data. Normally this data set is of differences (or percentage returns) whereas in your case you may working with price levels. One works with changes as opposed to levels because the latter introduces spurious correlations into the correlation/covariance matrix one must spectrally decompose to carry out the analysis. Anyway, I can go on, but for your purposes, PCA doesnt seem necessary.

Comment: For one thing you only have two variables -- no need to eliminate variables here (that don't add information by way of explaining variance), which is what PCA is used for. But in theory you can still proceed. WHile i could get into the details it would take too long to write-up carefully. Just search the web and you'll find someone else who's done so. For starters however, make sure work with % differences of each series.