# Step-by-Step PCA algorithm (checking correctness without math packages)

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, pca, covariance-estimation

I would appreciate if someone could correct me if i am wrong in my suggestion.

**I am using PCA to :**

- find measure of **cointegration** between selected assets
- find the eigenvector and its portfolio with a **market-neutral position** (min variance)

Unfortunately i am not sure whether i am doing it the right way. Here is my algorithm :

- getting the base matrix N x M : N - number of assets, M - number of history samples
- getting simple covariance matrix : Cov = E[(X - E[X])(Y - E[Y])]
- solving eigenproblem using Jacobi's Rotation method : [example][1]
- finding the index of the biggest eigenvalue by module : MinVariance = Min(Abs(eigenvalue))
- eigenvector can be found as a column in the rotation matrix by index of eigenvalue

**The question is :** did i miss something in this list of actions according to my initial purposes mentioned above?

> I am asking because i already calculated these weights for selected
>   currencies but they look odd to me because e.g. EURUSD and GBPUSD seem
>   to be opposite to each other when everyone knows that they are highly
>   correlated and moves together most of the time
>
> http://c.mql5cdn.com/3/28/USDCHFM1.png
>
> Here is my implementation of PCA on a C++ similar language called MQL
>
> http://www.mql5.com/ru/forum/16512/page3#comment_732844 (see
>   attachment)

Comment: You ask too much in one question. To answer a part: no: minimal variance is not related to the largest eigenvalue but rather too the smallest. And: inverting a matrix is not an estimator - what do you mean? Please rephrase the question. It starts with PCA and then goes to shrinkage. There is too much going on in this question

Comment: Simplified my question - it is only about correctness of PCA algorithm now

Comment: And what about this answer - i presume it says that minimum eigenvalue points to minimum variance, i mean this quotation : "As a side note, you could form a eigenportfolio that has minimum variance by identifying a principal component with a low eigenvalue"

Comment: @Richard: in addition i found this answer saying that biggest eigenvalue adds the most variance to the portfolio so i presume that opposite suggestion about min variance is also true - http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/4607/how-to-make-the-final-interpretation-of-pca?rq=1

Comment: Yes .. as far as I rememeber you had something like "largest eigenvalue" and "small variance". If you know that large eigenvalue measn large variance and vice-versa then it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this question.

**Steps used, in short :**

- get matrix N x M where N - number of assets, M - number of history
  samples
- normalize all samples using logarithms and mean to have returns instead of some asset specific values
- obtain covariance matrix, or correlation, if you want to avoid
  influence of volatility
- solve eigenproblem using SVD and Jacobi's rotation on covariance
  matrices
- Jacobi rotation returns two matrices - eigenvectors and eigenvalues

**Understanding results :**

- eigenvalue stands for variance of the portfolio's spread
- choosing max eigenvalue means selecting direction of entire portfolio
- choosing min eigenvalue means selecting periodic, noise or error component of portfolio with min variance
- each value in eigenvector is weighting coefficient for relevant asset
  in portfolio which asset needs to be multiplied by to get back to initial course
- eigenvector is a column in rotation matrix taken by index of selected
  eigenvalue

**Resources :**

- The best step-by-step tutorial on PCA is
  http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/cosc453/student_tutorials/principal_components.pdf
- The best theoretical explanation of PCA is
  https://georgemdallas.wordpress.com/2013/10/30/principal-component-analysis-4-dummies-eigenvectors-eigenvalues-and-dimension-reduction/
- Implementation in C#
  http://crsouza.blogspot.com/2009/09/principal-component-analysis-in-c.html
- Implementation in R http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/factor.html